# Javascript style applied but no changed in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a dynamically built HTML tree that looks something like this

```
<ul>
    <li class="parent">Node 1</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li class="parent">Node 1.1</li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li class="leaf">Node 1.1.1</li>
                    <li class="leaf">Node 1.1.2</li>
                    <li class="leaf">Node 1.1.3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="parent">Node 1.2</li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li class="leaf">Node 1.2.1</li>
                    <li class="leaf">Node 1.2.2</li>
                    <li class="leaf">Node 1.2.3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<li class="parent">Node 2</li>
...
</ul>
```

which on the page ends up looking like

```
Node 1
    Node 1.1
        Node 1.1.1
        Node 1.1.2
        Node 1.1.3
    Node 1.2
        Node 1.2.1
        Node 1.2.2
        Node 1.2.3
Node 2
    ...
```

After the tree is built I call `$(.parent).next().toggle()` to hide all nodes except the main roots (Node 1, Node 2, etc). The user can then click on each node to open the next child nodes, or click on a filter button to only show one specific nodes, its children and its direct parents (filtering on Node 1.1.2 would mean showing only Node 1, Node 1.1, Node 1.1.2 and then it's children).

The filtering itself works, but now I want to open all parent nodes up until the filtered node. To do so I've got the following javascript code;

```
let el = e.target.parentNode;
while (el.parentNode) {
    el = el.parentNode;
    el.style.display = 'block';
}
```

where `e` is the click event. What this code is supposed to do is traverse up the DOM finding the clicked element's parents and setting their `display` style property to `block`, but this isn't happening. When I `console.log(el.style.display)` it says `block` though, so the styling is applied, it's just not shown in the HTML. Manually changing the `li`'s inline `display: none` value to `display: block` does exactly what I want it to do though.

I've also tried setting the style using `el.setAttribute('style', 'display: block!important')`, but to no avail. What am I missing?

```js
let el = e.target.parentNode;
while (el.parentNode) {
  el = el.parentNode;
  el.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="parent">Node 1</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li class="parent">Node 1.1</li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li class="leaf">Node 1.1.1</li>
          <li class="leaf">Node 1.1.2</li>
          <li class="leaf">Node 1.1.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="parent">Node 1.2</li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li class="leaf">Node 1.2.1</li>
          <li class="leaf">Node 1.2.2</li>
          <li class="leaf">Node 1.2.3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent">Node 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: is it possible to make a stackblitz from what you have ?

Comment: I'll see what I can do

Comment: @Crocsx Why not a stacksnippet right here

Comment: What changes are you expecting to see when you change the style to block?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please turn it into a [mcve]

Comment: `let el = e.target.parentNode;` - is that element currently “hidden”? If so, you neglected to make it visible again - because you are not setting the style of _that_ element, but you are moving on to the _next_ element first, `el = el.parentNode;` - only after that you start setting display to block again.

Comment: The tree structure would be more logic and much easier to handle, if the children would be true children instead of them being siblings.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
.HideX{
 display:none;
};
</style>
<body>
<ul>
    <li class="parent">Node 1
        <ul>
            <li class="parent">Node 1.1
                <ul>
                    <li class="leaf">Node 1.1.1</li>
                    <li class="leaf">Node 1.1.2</li>
                    <li class="leaf">Node 1.1.3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="parent">Node 1.2
                <ul>
                    <li class="leaf">Node 1.2.1</li>
                    <li class="leaf">Node 1.2.2</li>
                    <li class="leaf">Node 1.2.3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 
</ul>
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
 $("li").click(function(e) {
  if( $(this).find('>ul').hasClass('.HideX') ){ // if Hide
  // then Remove Hide State
   $(this).children('ul').removeClass('.HideX').children('li').slideUp();
   e.stopPropagation(); // this is to prevent other item toggle because this event
  }
  else{ // if Not Hide
  // then Add Hide State
   $(this).children('ul').addClass('.HideX').children('li').slideDown();
   e.stopPropagation(); // this is to prevent other item toggle because this event
  }
 });

});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Something like this?